# How can I make a dialog ? How can I fix this?

Tags: android

First of all, sorry about my English. I Am trying to create a dialog with 2 buttons and textview. When I click a button the program skips the first part and jumps to the second.
How can I fix this? My goal is to do a dialog like:

- +Hi, how are you?
- -Good
- -Bad
- (Clicked to bad)
- +Why do you feel bad ?
- -Because he bited me
- -Because I Am wounded

  Thanks for the help :| !

  ```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  btnT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnT);
  btnF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnF);
  tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
  yazdir(R.array.metin1,R.array.secim1,0);

      //first part
  btnT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          yazdir(R.array.metin2,R.array.secim2,0);
      }
  });
  btnF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          yazdir(R.array.metin2,R.array.secim2,1);
      }
  });

  //second part


  btnT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          yazdir(R.array.metin3,R.array.secim3,0);
      }
  });
  btnF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          yazdir(R.array.metin3,R.array.secim3,1);
      }
  });

     }





     private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
     @Override
    public void run() {
      tv.setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
      if(mIndex <= mText.length()) {
          mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, 20);
      }
      else {
          btnT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          btnF.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }
     };

   public void yazdir(int metinGirisi,int secimGirisi,int metinIndex) {
  // Yazı

  text=getResources().getStringArray(metinGirisi);
  mText = text[metinIndex];
  mIndex = 0;
  tv.setText("");
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
  mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, 20);

  // Buton

  secim=getResources().getStringArray(secimGirisi);
  btnT.setText(secim[0]);
  btnF.setText(secim[1]);
  btnF.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  btnT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


   }
  ```

Comment: more than 80.why ?

Comment: Just to know if a database should fit your needs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use [this](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) library

According to your requirement, your code should look like:

```
    MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
        .content("Hi, how are you?")
        .positiveText("Good")
        .negativeText("Bad")
        .show();

    // Handle Good click
    dialog.onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
             new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)   
            .content("You clicked Good")
            .positiveText("OK")              
            .show();
        }
    })

    // Handle Bad click
    dialog.onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
             new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)   
            .content("Why feeling bad?")
            .positiveText("Because he bit me")
            .negativeText("Because I am wounded")
            .show();   
        }
    })
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: thanks for try to help but it didn't help.my need is the first part will have to wait until button is clicked.Then second part will activate.and so on

Comment: Have you tried the above code. It does just that.

Comment: There's really no need for a library... What's wrong with the standard AlertDialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Dialog Fragments in your Activity that uses the AlertDialog and then call the next dialog using an Intent. Here are links to Android developer site about dialogs and the other Intents:

Creating a Dialog Fragment:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Intents:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html